# installing Canon LBP-810 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, canon

How to set working Canon LBP-810 on newest Ubuntu 18.04? Trvehere is no official driver for 64bit linux system
thanks

Comment: Have you tried the 32-bit version?

Answer (score 0):

It actually appears that someone reverse engineered the protocol used which lead to the capt driver.

There are instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) for ubuntu 14.04, but you can definitely compile it from source. The git repo for it is located [here](https://github.com/agalakhov/captdriver) and it should be fairly self explanatory to install with the instructions in INSTALL.git and the INSTALL file.